# Transpose columns to rows of data

Tags: regex, bash, transpose

I have a project which surpasses my skill.  My end goal is to take processed data into a scatter graph.  To do this I need to convert log output from this format:

```
        Counter Name     Port: 1/8/x1     Port: 1/8/x2     Port: 1/8/x3     Port: 1/8/x4
  ================== ================ ================ ================ ================
         IfInOctets:          5470343          5520353          5628425          5685539
      IfInUcastPkts:             8878             9029             9345             9512
     IfInNUcastPkts:            17779            17755            17755            17755
       IfInPktDrops:                0                0                0                0
       IfInDiscards:            26657            26784            27100            27267
         IfInErrors:                0                0                0                0
```

to

```
Port number,IfInErrors
```

value.

To reduce the unnecessary labels I use awk and other commands iteratively.

```
for i in `ls *.log`; do 
    awk '/Counter Name|IfInDiscards/ {print $0}' $i.txt
done
```

(again my skill level is "muy pequeña).  The command is:

```
for i in `ls *.log`; do 
    awk '/Counter Name|IfInDiscards/ {print $0}' $i.txt
done
```

I next discard unneeded data using `sed`

```
sed -i 's/Counter Name//g' *.txt    #Delete Counter name and IfInDiscards
sed -i 's/IfInErrors://g'  *.txt
sed -i 's/Port: //g'                #Eliminate unnecessary Port: and space
sed -i 's/  */ /g' 
sed -i "s/ /,/g"                    #Convert white space to commas
```

That leaves me with clean columnar data.

```
  Column1,column2,Column3,Column4,Column5
Row1 ,1/8/x1,1/8/x2,1/8/x3,1/8/x4
Rowd2 ,0,0,0,0
```

So, my next item is to drop the leading comma (Column1).

```
  Column1,column2,Column3,Column4
Row1  1/8/x1,1/8/x2,1/8/x3,1/8/x4
Row2  0,0,0,0
```

Then the heavy lift for me is to get the data into this format (concatenated column + row data, a command and column + row data).

```
Col1+row1,col1+row2
Col2+row1,col2+row2
```

.
.
end

There will be always be four columns and up to 100 rows.

The rub is I don't know how to convert this to code.

As always,  I'm not just looking for a simple "can someone do this for me" approach as I want to build my skill level.  Copy+paste is fast but I don't learn.

That being said, I am looking for guidance.

Comment: Are you trying to do this all in the shell?

Comment: yes, I am.  I'm learning python but it's slow going without a peer to discuss with and work is always pretty busy.

Answer (score 1):

This can all be done in a single `awk` command. Use an array to hold the port numbers from the first row.

```
for file in *.log; do
    awk '/Counter Name/ { for (col = 4; col <= NF; col += 2) port[col/2] = $col }
         /IfInErrors/ { for (col = 2; col <= NF; col++) printf("%s,%d\n", port[col], $col) }' < "$file"
done
```

The first line of the `awk` script matches the line with the port number headings. Loops through the columns by 2, and creates an array containing the port numbers.

The second line matches the lines that contain the input error values. It then goes through the remaining columns, printing the port number from the above array followed by the value in that column.

If you want to be able to transpose multiple rows of value into columns, you'll need to use arrays to save all the values, rather than printing immediately when you see the counter you want.

```
    awk '/Counter Name/ { for (col = 4; col <= NF; col += 2) port[col/2] = $col; maxcols = NF/2 }
         /IfInErrors/ { for (col = 2; col <= NF; col++) inErrors[col] = $col }
         /IfInOctets/ { for (col = 2; col <= NF; col++) inOctets[col] = $col }
        END { for ( col = 2; col <= maxcols; col++) printf("%s,%d,%d\n", port[col], inErrors[col], inOctets[col]); }
    ' < "$file"
done
```

You can repeat the lines like `/IfInErrors/` and `/IfInOctets/` for each of the values you want to include in the output. Change the name of the array you save the value to, and add them to the `printf` in the `END` block.

Comment: Thank you.  It's going to take a little time for me to dissect the meaning but the script will be grade.  I tried the script right away and it worked very well.  Again, thank you.

Comment: The forth column isn't processing correctly and I do not understand why.

The pattern follows like this

The the neatly transposted columns to rows.  Excet for one line.
1/1/x1,0
1/1/x2,0
1/1/x3,0
,01/x4   <=== And this patter repeats.

I am unfamiliar with the syntax being used so I can't step throught the log.  Could you help once again?

Regard

Comment: I just tested it with the sample file in the question and it worked. There must be something different in the actual file you're using.

Comment: Yes, I noticed there is.  The number of columns vary from four to three.  BTW,  sorry for the very late reply but I've been pulled away on a number of P1s.  :(  Now I am trying to add one more piece of data.  Could you outline the flow of your script so I can better understand?

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd paragraphs of the answer explain what each line in the script is doing. What part of it don't you understand? The number of columns shouldn't matter, it just loops through all of them in the `for (col = ...)` loops.

Comment: { for (col = 4; col <= NF; col += 2) port[col/2] = $col } and { for (col = 4; col <= NF; col += 2) port[col/2] = $col }.  These are beyond my experience.  :( I think I understand that col =4 means there are four columns.  The semicolon separates the next command that follows.  NF means, I think, the total number of fi3lds is four.  Next it appears if col -s less than or equal to "something happens."  After that I am lost.  Now I want to add a third item so I am not sure what would needed to be done.  A thrid line similar  to line three?

Comment: No, it doesn't mean there are 4 columns. It means to start looking at field 4. Each time through the loop we add 2 to `col`, and test whether we've gone past `NF`, which is the total number of columns.

Comment: For example, in the header line in your question, when `col` is `4`, `$col` is `1/8/x1`. The next time through the loop, `col` becomes `6` and `$col` is `1/8/x2`. This repeats as long as `col < NF`, and `NF` is `10`.

Comment: If you want to add another element, copy the `/IfInErrors/` line, and change the pattern that you match.

Comment: Ok,  I will try a new line.  Thx.

Comment: Yes!  it worked mostly.  I still get this:                                              1/1/x1,0
1/1/x2,0
1/1/x3,0
,01/x4
1/1/x1,0
1/1/x2,0
1/1/x3,0
,01/x4
1/1/x5,0
1/1/x6,0
1/1/x7,1960586315
,2281664769

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments. Add it to the question.

Comment: There's no formatting in comments, so I can't tell what your result really looks like.

Comment: I just realized that you're trying to get something like `portnum,inErrors,inOctets` all on one line for each port. My script won't do that, because print prints all the lines at once as soon as it sees the `ifInErrors`.

Comment: To do what you want, you'll need to save each of the values in an array. Then use an `END` block that prints the elements of each array on a single line.